# Codeigniter assetlib-pro does not output anything

Tags: php, codeigniter

My folder structure for assets folder looks like this

> project_root_folder -> assets -> css -> {stylesheet.css, sample.css, something.css}
>
> project_root_folder -> assets -> js -> {jquery.min.js, sample.js, something.js}
>
> project_root_folder -> assets -> cache
>
> project_root_folder -> system -> plugins -> csstidy
>
> project_root_folder -> system -> plugins -> jsmin.php

Configuration code in `application/config/assetlibpro.php`

```
$config['alp_csstidy_basepath']    = "/system/plugins/csstidy";

$config['alp_jsmin']    = "/system/plugins/jsmin.php";

$config['alp_asset_dir'] = 'assets/';//TRAILING SLASH!

$config['alp_cache_dir_css'] = 'assets/cache/';//TRAILING SLASH!

$config['alp_cache_dir_js'] = 'assets/cache/';//TRAILING SLASH!
```

In my `config/autoload.php`

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('assetlibpro');`

In my controllers,

```
$this->assetlibpro->add_css('stylesheet.css'); // Stylesheet file

$this->assetlibpro->add_js('jquery-2.1.0.min.js'); // JavaScript file

$data['common_css']=$this->assetlibpro->output('css'); // Store the CSS in the variable

$data['homepage_js']=$this->assetlibpro->output('js'); // Store the JS in the variable

$this->load->view('main-homepage', $data); // Load homepage view
```

In the main-homepage.php,

```
echo $common_css;

echo $homepage_js;
```

But the page does not throw any errors or output the CSS and JS. What is the mistake I do?

Comment: check apache error log i hope sumthing you can find out there

Comment: There is no related errors related to this in the error log.

Comment: Did you enable the error_reporing(E_ALL); in the index.php of codeignitor

Comment: Yeah the environment is set as `development` with error level `E_ALL`.